# Cant check $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session

Hello i have problem:  in login.php file i'm storing $_SESSION['$myusername'];
I try to check that SESSIOn username in page.php file, if session not exists it redirects back to login.php. I try to login with valid user but i'm redirecting back to login.php
I dont know where is the problem.

login.php:

```
 <?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="2"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message 
};  
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
//store data:
$_SESSION['$myusername'];

//next page:


header("location:page.php");
}

else {

include 'index.php';
$error[] = '<b><h5>Invalid Username or Password!</b>';


if(isset($error) && is_array($error))
{
   echo "<div class='content1'>" . implode("<br />", $error) . "</div>";
};

};
?>
```

page.php :

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['$myusername']))
    {
         header("Location: login.php")
    }


?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Do you have a call to `session_start` in login.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Page.php you shouldn't include the $ when checking the session variable:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['$myusername']))
```

should be:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
```

In Login.php you must set the session variable:

```
if($count==1){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  //store data:
  $_SESSION['$myusername'];
  //next page:
  header("location:page.php");
}
```

should be:

```
if($count==1){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  //store data:
  $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
  //next page:
  header("location:page.php");
}
```

Login.php also needs a call to session_start() at the top.

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas - Thanks, I'm assuming you also have a call to session_start() in login.php?

Comment: Yup i forgot it. I'm beginner in php ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is in your `login.php` page, you don't start the session. Add `session_start()` to the beginning of the page.

Second, you never assign a value to the session-variable. Try:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
```

Note, I also removed the `$` inside the session-key name. Because of this, in your `page.php` page you'll also have to access it with `isset($_SESSION['myusername'])`. You could always keep the `$`, but I don't believe that's what you mean to use.